# is theres a function to change the datagridview cell values?

Tags: vb.net

[image]

after i scan a barcode the data will automaticaly display to datagridview, and my problem is how to change the cell value on quantity in DGV using textbox?

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you can even be asking this question. You would have to have done no research at all on the subject and, if that's the case, it's far too soon to be asking a question here. SO is for stuff that you have tried and can't work out, not for stuff that you can't be bothered to work out. This one could be worked out with two minutes and a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway.. After scanning, give focus to the TextboxQty

`DGV.Item("qty", DGV.CurrentRow.Index).Value = TextboxQty.Text`

use the code in TextboxQty's lost focus / validating event. Instead of "qty" use DGV's qty column name or column number.